# Facebook Tab on pages

Tags: facebook

Whats the best way to develop a tab on facebook in a facebook page with content inside it? Would it just be html within that tab?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest way is to install a 3rd party iframe App on your Facebook Page.  You can find these Apps by searching for "iframe" in Facebook's search.  Once you have one of these Apps installed, you can customize the HTML/CSS/JS of the iframe, which will then be reflected on you Page Tab.  Alternatively, you could create your own Facebook App and install it as an iframe in your Facebook Page.  This will achieve the same thing, and may give you more control, but you will have to host the html/css/js files yourself and it will be more work.

Answer (score 1):

I recently have the same need.
To just place a facebook tab containing just a static html with text and image.
Here are the steps. It can be quite a nightmare to review the documentation of Facebook since it is always in change.

1. In the home page, click in the settings button. There is a link "Create application". You have to be sure to be in the Facebook development section
2. In the Create Application home page. In the upper menu there is the button "Applications". Here will be listed all your applications. If this is the first time, again the button "Create a new app"
   3.Enter the information requested. Name of the application, an identifier (I prefer the same display name without spaces) and choose a category.
3. As a security step, a captcha is shown. Just fill with the characters in the screen.
4. Since your tab is an html. You have to host this file in your own server in order to have a path. The first tricky thing here is to convert this file into a php, asp, or similar extension. since Facebook uses GET or POST protocol to send information. You have to ensure that your file understands this requests. So, your server must accept the corresponding programming language. Even if your tab doesn't have any real code.
5. The configuration of your app is shown in screen. In the left menu, the option "configuration" displays the options to activate your tab.
6. click "Add plattform" button and select Facebook tab
7. fill the information required with the corresponding URLs. Note: Facebook always requires secured URLs so make sure that your server or hosting service has the SSL certificate validated.
8. Upload the image of your tab to be shown in the home of your profile in your tab section.
9. ok, so far we are good. Now. This was a long search. There is no longer the "Add to my webpage" link anywhere. So use this link to access to that hidden link. [here](http://www.jibecompany.com/2012/add-a-facebook-page-tab-application-to-your-page/) Basically you enter the facebook app id and the URL of the hosted file.
10. Then you select the facebook page where you want to link this tab. And that's it!

note: the alternative to the link is this: (https://www.facebook.com/dialog/pagetab?app_id=YOUR_APP_ID&next=YOUR_URL )

Hope this helps. It was a waste of time when I have to search for the details so I want to share this.