# How to integrate the facebook app in Page Tab

Tags: facebook, tabs

I am trying to Make a simple facebook tab landing page with an app, and I cannot seem to get it to work. I tried researching this, but a lot of the tutorials on how to do this is are out of date because they change the process on how to do this so often. I am attaching my settings screen and the error I am getting in a screen shot. Not sure what is wrong with my base url, but i know for a fact the page is at the location specified.

[here is the screen shot](http://greenwichorchids.com/facebook/teqa/issue.jpg)

Comment: I create a list of steps 

[Facebook tab on pages][1]


  [1]: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7670412/facebook-tab-on-pages/21939866#21939866

Answer (score 0):

Be sure that in the `Page Tab URL` you point to a file in your server that already exist in your server.
If you can't access the page, try to add the whole file name in the `Page Tab URL`
like: http://mydomain.tld/filename.php

to start using the api take a look at the docs here:

**Facebook JS API Documentation**
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/

**Facebook PHP API Documentation**
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/

Answer (score -1):

The Settings where you trying to configure the Tab is just not correct. The easiest way to do this is to install http://apps.facebook.com/iframehost and configure it the way you want!

Comment: -1... this is the correct place to configure the settings for a page tab application.